# 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll ("Incorrect syntax near ')'.")?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, exception, ado.net

Hey this is my code and this is the error I get:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   System.Data.dll ("Incorrect syntax near ')'.")

---

```
void addMember() 
{
    try 
    {
       //con.Open();
        String EmpID = txtEmpID.Text.ToString().Trim();
        String EmployeeName = txtEmpID.Text.ToString().Trim();
        String UserName = txtUsername.Text.ToString().Trim();
        String UserType = cmbUserType.GetItemText(cmbUserType.SelectedItem);
        String PassWord = txtPassword.Text.ToString().Trim();
        SqlCommand addUser = new SqlCommand("insert into  userDetails(@empID ,@employeeName ,@userName , @userType, @password)", con);
        addUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empID", EmpID));
        addUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@employeeName", EmployeeName));
        addUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userName", UserName));
        addUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userType", UserType));
        addUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", PassWord));

        int x = addUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (x > 0)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted", "User Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        //con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
    }
```

Comment: Do not write an insert into query without specifying the column names. If, for any reason you add a new column to that table your code will break. (and you will avoid this error from the start)

Comment: why is it that people post code on here, but panic and refuse to learn to use the debugger..? `Google is a great free tool for learning SQL Syntax`

Comment: A debugger wouldn't really help you here...it's a sql syntax problem. But is there a reason you need to use raw SQL commands, vs entity framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have missed the [`Values`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) keyword:

```
SqlCommand addUser = new SqlCommand("insert into userDetails Values(@empID ," +
                                                              ^^^^
                                    "@employeeName ,@userName , @userType, @password)", con);
```

Comment: While correct, as Steve pointed out above, this only works as long as the columns in the database are in the exact order you expect them to be.  Which may be a reasonable assumption. But if you use EF (and tools to ensure your DB is in-sync with your EDM) you can catch/prevent mismatches between your application code and the database schema a lot more readily.

Comment: Thanks alot guys 

cant beleive i missed that

Comment: Thanks for the support